# How to concurrently execute a method in c#?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need to run a method n number of times in parallel in c#.The method doesn't return anything , it just triggers a lambda function concurrently. I need the triggers to be done in parallel.

I am now using:

```
Parallel.For(0,5,new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism=5},I=>{my function();});
```

This triggers the method 5 times in a loop. can somebody please suggest a better way using threads or tasks.

Comment: Why do you need a "better way"? What would constitute a "better way"?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and the problems you are having. `Parallel.For` should not wait for the results of the first call to do the second.

Comment: This is a highly optimal way of doing it, not sure there exists a significantly better way.

Comment: Does Parallel. For really execute the calls paralelly. I have read that they are used for core optmisation where paralelly operations can be run on multiple core I want to run this program on a lambda , so need to know if there is any other way of executing methods all at the same time.